# Ficar mostrando a data e hora no browser com javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá.

Quero exibir na página a data e hora. Para isso, comecei fazendo o pequeno teste para exibir uma contagem regressiva:

```js
var tempo=60;
function session(time) {
  time=this.tempo;
  if (this.tempo>0) {
    tempo--;
    document.write(tempo);
  }
}
function pegaSession() {
  setInterval(session, 10000);
}
session(tempo);
```

Não tratei o tempo ainda, pois quero mostrar decrescente, depois que resolver este detalhe, trabalho com a função parseInt e ParseFloat().

Comment: Obs: o correto seria `parseInt`

Comment: @Silvio Andorinha já corrigido.

Answer (score 7):

Acontece que nesse caso a função `session()` é chamada apenas uma vez na ultima linha do código `session(tempo);` e depois em nenhum momento você chama a função `pegaSession()` que é a que da inicio no setInterval

Faça a seguinte alteração

```js
var tempo=60;
var interval;

function session(time) {
time=this.tempo;
if (this.tempo>0) {
    tempo--;
    document.body.innerHTML='';
    document.write(tempo);    
}
else
{
    clearInterval(interval)
}
}

function pegaSession() {
interval = setInterval(session, 1000);
}
pegaSession();
```

Como pode notar no final do código eu chamo o `pegaSession()` para assim ele iniciar o setInterval

> Obs: 10000 milissegundos é equivalente a 10 segundos, se for usar esse setInterval para marcação de segundos o correto seria 1000 equivalente a 1 segundo

***E limpando o intervalo como sugerido pelo nosso amigo @TobyMosque ;)***

Comment: Na verdade, mesmo chamando a pegaSession(), não resolve. Dá o erro: wyciwyg://36/http://localhost/objeto/principal.php

Comment: @AndréNascimento execute esse código exatamente como está na resposta, e poderá ver que está funcionando normalmente

Comment: Silvio, a resposta é muito boa, mas acredito que seja interresante limpar este Intervalo quando o tempo for igual ou menor que zero, afinal não é legal deixar uma função que não faz nada rodando a toa ;D. https://jsfiddle.net/uz2qyrg2/

Comment: @TobyMosque editei lá ;)

Answer (score 2):

André nascimento, se tudo que deseja é mostrar a Data e Hora no Browser, aconselho ignorar este contador e pega a Hora do Sistema, como acredito que você deseja mostrar quando tempo falta para a Sessão do usuario expirar, vou colocar um exemplo onde o tempo se esgota em 15 segundos:

```js
var interval = 1000;
var dataValidade = new Date();
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

dataValidade.setSeconds(dataValidade.getSeconds() + 15);
//dataValidade.setHours(dataValidade.getHours() + 1);

var verificarSessao = function () {
  var dataAtual = new Date();
  var tempoRestante = new Date(dataValidade.getTime() - dataAtual.getTime());         
  
  if (tempoRestante.getTime() < 0)
  {
    countdown.textContent = "O seu tempo acabou"
  }
  else
  {    
    tempoRestante.setMinutes(tempoRestante.getMinutes() + tempoRestante.getTimezoneOffset())
    countdown.textContent = "O tempo se esgota em " +  tempoRestante.toTimeString().substring(0, 8) + ".";
    setTimeout(verificarSessao, interval);
  }
}

verificarSessao();
```

```html
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

caso queira aumentar o tempo, basta adicionar mais tempo a variavel dataValidade.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer apenas um relógio, basta você fazer uma saída desse tipo:

```
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="count_label_ms"></div>
        <script>
        var init = function() {
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
            var dataRelogio = new Date();
            var times = [((dataRelogio.getHours() < 10) ? '0': '') +
                           dataRelogio.getHours(),
                         ((dataRelogio.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0': '') +
                           dataRelogio.getMinutes(),
                           dataRelogio.getSeconds()].join(":");

            var strData = [((dataRelogio.getDate() < 10) ? '0': '') + 
                            dataRelogio.getDate() + '/' +
                          ((dataRelogio.getMonth() < 10) ? '0': '') + 
                            dataRelogio.getMonth() + '/' +
                            dataRelogio.getFullYear(), times];
            document.getElementById('count_label_ms').innerHTML = strData.join(' ');
                       });
                   }
        </script> 
</body>
```

Se for um contador regressivo, você pode fazer isso de duas maneiras:

Em javascript puro:
http://jsfiddle.net/fk2unkb9/31/
Ou em AngularJS: http://jsfiddle.net/fk2unkb9/29/

Comment: copiei, colei no eclipse, mas não exibiu. Li superficialmente o código, não parei para analisá-lo e estudar com calma.

Comment: Não entendi? Qual o problema?

Comment: Não mostra nenhum erro. Como foram me passadas várias soluções, vou estudá-las, pois não posso falar muito sem conhecer e qualquer coisa, comento, até evita comentários meu, como leigo.

Answer (score 1):

Caso queira mostrar a hora atual mesmo, use o objeto *Date()* do javascript.

**Observação**

Como os meses são retornados em números e o dia da semana também, eu criei um array para os meses e um para os dias da semana e usei o número retornado pelo objeto para selecionar o dia e mês certos nos Arrays.

```js
window.onload = setInterval(horario, 1000);

function horario() {
  var relogio = document.querySelector("#relogio");
  var d = new Date();
  var seg = d.getSeconds();
  var min = d.getMinutes();
  var hr = d.getHours();
  var dia = d.getDate();
  var mes = d.getMonth();
  var meses = ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"];
  var diaSem = d.getDay();
  var diasSemana = ["Domingo","Segunda-Feira","Terça-Feira","Quarta-Feira","Quinta-Feira","Sexta-Feira","Sábado"];

  relogio.innerHTML = diasSemana[diaSem] + ", " + dia + " de " + meses[mes] + ", " + hr + ":" + min + ":" + seg;
}
```

```html
<span id="relogio"></span>
```

Comment: no lugar de montar a string na mão, pq não usa o [Date.prototype.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)? um exemplo: `relogio.innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleString();`

Comment: Ainda não conhecia esse método, mas muito obrigado, fui tentar ajudar e acabei aprendendo rs.

Answer (score 0):

```
function DataHora() {  
        var data = new Date();  
        tempo.innerHTML = data;  
        var dataBr = tempo.toLocaleString();  
        setTimeout("DataHora()", 1000);  
    }  

<body onload="DataHora()">  

<span id=tempo></span>
```